# algorithm to narrow down ranges created from random number/noise generator

Tags: algorithm, math

I implemented a random number/noise generator. (Perlin noise, to be specific). 
However, the random number generated from the algorithm(taken from wikipedia) returns float number from -1 to 1. I need it so that it returns from 0 to 1. Is there any way I can narrow it down without messing the number distribution/pattern?

If code is needed, I'll post it here, but if it's possible, I'd love to mess/add something to the generated number(like multiplying with -1 if number is negative) so that it'll be from 0 to 1 (without breaking the number distribution of course) 
Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: What's the distribution? Why won't `(r+1)/2` won't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll frequently encounter the task to [bijectively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) map one specific source interval into target interval. In your case, the source interval is `[-1, 1]`, and the target interval is `[0,1]` <sup>*</sup>. But this does not really matter. The pattern is always the same: To map a value `xSource` from a range `[sourceMin, sourceMax]` to a value `xTarget` from the range `[targetMin, targetMax]`, you can always use the formula

```
alpha = ((xSource - sourceMin) / (sourceMax - sourceMin));
xTarget = targetMin + alpha * (targetMax - targetMin);
```

<sub>(In the particular case that you asked about, this will simplify to `xTarget = xSource * 0.5 + 0.5`, as already pointed out in the other answer - but it's always good to know how to treat something like this generically)</sub>

---

<sup>*</sup> You should, however, consider whether you're talking about *open*, *closed* or *half-open* intervals. See [Interval - Including or excluding endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Including_or_excluding_endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
if x<0
   x *=-1
```

or

```
x = random()*0.5+0.5
```

would work i think.

Comment: I have no idea what the distribution he's facing but for something like [Beta Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), it skews the distribution. (the 2nd is what I suggested in comments).

Comment: I didn't see your comment until after i posted sorry

Answer (score 0):

*the harequin*'s method of multiplying by -1 will definitely give you the correct range. However, I'm not sure if simply flipping the sign will maintain the same statistical distribution or not, so I'm going to give a slightly more complex way that will definitely maintain your distribution.

I'll write it as a function, where the input is your random number from -1 to 1, and the output is the number resized onto your 0 to 1 range.

```
float rerange(float original)
{
  //this reranges the -1 to 1 to instead be 0 to 2
  original = original + 1;
  //this reranges the 0 to 2 to instead be 0 to 1
  original = original / 2.0;
  //now we have modified the original number to fall in the range 0 to 1. All done.
  return original;
}
```

So note that the process is simply to raise the bottom bound to 0 with addition, and then to divide the size of the range down. This technique can be applied to achieve any range, and doesn't even have to start at zero if you do one more addition at the end to readjust the bottom bound of your range. If you want the expand the size of the range instead of shrinking it like we did, you can just multiply it instead of dividing it. Let me know if you wanted this in any particular language.